# "Color" type lookup issue SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am kind of surprise by this error :

When I use below code and use for background color it works fine

```
var blueColor = Color(red: 44 / 255, green: 89 / 255, blue: 255 / 255)
```

But starts giving error  if I make it

```
  var blueColor : Color = Color(red: 44 / 255, green: 89 / 255, blue: 255 / 255)
```

[image]
[image]

**Similarly when I am trying to return Color type from function getting similar issue**

[image]

Comment: 8-bit color is for last millennium; please do not use it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine here (tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15), so it seems you have declared custom `Color` type somewhere in your code.

Try to use with module prefix wherever you need standard type, like

```
var bgColor : SwiftUI.Color = .black
```

Comment: Seems like the SDK I am importing have declared Custom public Struct Color